# How to monitor telnetlib3 connection for termination from host side continuously using asyncio

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, networking, python-multithreading

I am working on creating a telnet client in Python 3 using the telnetlib3 and asyncio modules. More specifically the telnet client is to connect with VLC Media Player's telnet interface. I have been able to successfully implement the client and establish a connection and issue commands over telnet. The client prompts the user for input then writes it to the host.

**My problem:**
If under any situation the remote host (VLC window) closes then the client keeps waiting for input instead of terminating automatically. I want to monitor the connection simultaneously while the interpreter is waiting for input via the `writer.is_closing()` function and if it returns true then I want it to exit or terminate.

**My approach:** I know one way is to run a monitor function on a parallel thread which can monitor the connection and exit the script but I am also aware that asyncio can also do concurrent tasks as the official thread module documentation also has recommended to use asyncio hence, I want to implement the monitor function and the client by using asyncio and also reduce the library imports.

My Code:

```Python3
import telnetlib3
import asyncio
import json
from helpers import LoopBreakException, send_password

# THIS IS THE FUNCTION THAT I WANT TO BE CONCURRENT
async def monitor_connection():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(3)  # Adjust the interval as needed
        if writer.is_closing():
            raise LoopBreakException(
                "Unexpected termination of VLC. Connection lost. Exiting...")


async def connection():
    global reader, writer
        
    try:
        with open("config.json") as config:
            try:
                configuration = json.loads(config.read())
                # Telnet host, port and password
                host, port, key, token = configuration["host"], configuration[
                    "port"], configuration['key'].encode("utf-8"), configuration['token'].encode("utf-8")
            except json.JSONDecodeError as JDE:
                logger.error(JDE)
                return 0
    except FileNotFoundError as FNFE:
        logger.error(FNFE)
        return 0

    # Connect to the Telnet host
    try:
        reader, writer = await telnetlib3.open_connection(host, port)
    except ConnectionRefusedError as CRE:
        logger.error(CRE)
        return 0
    # Login to interface

    print(await reader.readuntil(b"Password:"))
    writer.write(send_password(key, token)+"\n")
    # I KNOW THIS IS ONE WAY TO CREATE A TASK BUT
    # I AM NOT ABLE TO FIGURE OUT WHERE TO AWAIT IT OR ANY OTHER WAY TO IMPLEMENT THIS
    task = asyncio.create_task(monitor_connection())
    del key
    del token
    await reader.readuntil(b">")

    async def Send_command_Get_output(command):
        if command == "quit":
            writer.write(command + "\n")
            print(await (reader.readuntil()))
            writer.close()
            raise LoopBreakException(
                "Quit command sent to VLC. Closing connection.")
        elif command == "shutdown":
            writer.write(command + "\n")
            try:
                print(await (reader.readuntil(b"Shutting down.")))
            except asyncio.IncompleteReadError as e:
                print("Try failed. Doing partial read")
                print(e.partial)
            finally:
                writer.close()
                raise LoopBreakException("Shutdown completed")
        writer.write(command + "\n")
        try:
            buffer = await reader.readuntil(b">")
        except asyncio.IncompleteReadError as e:
            buffer = e.partial
        buffer = buffer.decode("utf-8")
        print(buffer)
        if writer.transport.is_closing():
            # Close the connection
            writer.close()
            raise LoopBreakException(
                "Unexpected termination of VLC. Connection lost. Exiting...")

    while not writer.is_closing():
        try:
            command = input("VLC> ").lower()
            await Send_command_Get_output(command)
        except LoopBreakException as LBE:
            print(LBE)
            break
    else:
        print("Remote host terminated unexpectedly.")

# Run the main function
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        asyncio.run(connection())
    except RuntimeError as RE:
        if "Event loop is closed" not in str(RE):
            raise RE
```

I want help regarding proper implementation of the `monitor_connection()` function or any other way to implement the same via asyncio preferably.

Help and suggestions regarding other code improvement is also appreciated.

Comment: 1. Use a read timeout. 2. Enable TCP keepalive. 3. If the peer closes the connection properly you won't block at all, you will get EOS from the read. You don't need async I/O for any of this.

Answer (score 1):

It's not as simple as you might be thinking... You'd better think a bit different. You must use protocols for that. No sleep calls must exist! In async world It's kinda code smell actually. Here is a very short example (not a copy-paste example one though)

```
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import *

import telnetlib3


class Connection:
    def __init__(self, host: str, port: int = 23) -> None:
        self._protocol: None | _Protocol = None
        self._address = host, port

    async def open(self):
        reader, writer = await telnetlib3.open_connection(
            *self._address, client_factory=self._create_protocol
        )

    def _create_protocol(self, **kwds):
        self._protocol = protocol = _Protocol(self, **kwds)
        return protocol


class _Protocol(telnetlib3.TelnetClient):
    def __init__(self, connection: Connection, *args, **kwds):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwds)
        self.connection = connection

    def eof_received(self):
        # telnetlib3.TelnetClient calls the connection_lost() here and returns None.
        # This causes asyncio to close the transport and register the connection_lost() to be called soon,
        # Hence we have the connection_lost() that is called twice.
        # Contributors know about this because they added logic similar to the "include guard"
        # from C to make the connection_lost() not to do things when it's a second call.
        pass

    def connection_lost(self, exc: None | Exception, /) -> None:
        # This is called each time when you connection is lost
        ...
```

This way you have an access to your connection instance right inside the protocol. So you can fire a callback method when connection is lost or something like that. Note I've divided those instances (the connection and the protocol). This is usefull if you wanna have a re-enterable connection instance (open and close and open again the same instance). You could write `client_factory=lambda **kw: self` and use the same class then, but... Be careful, there are pitfalls in there :) If you're still interested I could provide you with the next steps to take, because I have a gut feeling that you wanna interrupt your coroutine at random place once the connection is lost. It's not s trivial challenge...

You know though, are you sure you need such a complicated stuff? May be handling and exception is just enough?  You will get when you get disconnected while you are reading...

The next crucial thing I see -- your `input` call! It's a blocking call. All your concurrency die while you are waiting for your input to be done. You must use threads in this case.

```py
command = (await asyncio.to_thread(input, "VLC> ")).lower()
```

And if you really want concurrency you'd better to simultaneously wait for either connection is lost or input is ready (what would b completed first).

```py
# NOTE: input and disconnected are your tasks to wait...
asyncio.wait((input, disconnected), return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
```